# How to automate OTP in mail using selenium web driver 3.0 above version

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-ide

I need help for my project i have a scenario, where i will get one verification code on my mail id i want to get that verification code and use in my script.

Please let me know anybody has done something like that, thanks in advance

Comment: Your _code trials_?

Comment: Just guessing, you'd have to open your mail id in next Tab and read the first mail, through automation. Not very sure.

Comment: It's unclear to me how Selenium is relevant to this. Sure, something you do in Selenium will trigger the email, but then you just need to have your code wait for the arrival of the email and read it exactly as you would in any other context. Which basically reduces this question to one of how to read an email inbox from a Java application, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have done that.

Once you send OTP from the application. You have to use `javax.mail` and have to write the code to read the email from mailbox for provided emailid. and then extract the OTP using suitable regex from content you get.

First add these dependency if you are using Maven project otherwise you have to add same libraries in your project

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Create one class and use this code :

```
String hostName = "smtp.gmail.com";
String username = "email username"
String password = "email passeord"
int messageCount;
int unreadMsgCount;
String emailSubject;
Message emailMessage;

public MailReader() {
    Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();
    sysProps.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(sysProps, null);
        Store store = session.getStore();
        store.connect(hostName, username, password);
        Folder emailInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        emailInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        messageCount = emailInbox.getMessageCount();
        System.out.println("Total Message Count: " + messageCount);
        unreadMsgCount = emailInbox.getNewMessageCount();
        System.out.println("Unread Emails count:" + unreadMsgCount);
        emailMessage = emailInbox.getMessage(messageCount);
        emailSubject = emailMessage.getSubject();

        Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*)\" target"); // here you need to define regex as per you need
        Matcher pageMatcher =
                linkPattern.matcher(emailMessage.getContent().toString());

        while (pageMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found OTP " + pageMatcher.group(1));
        }
        emailMessage.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
        emailInbox.close(true);
        store.close();

    } catch (Exception mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```